# std::lexicographical_compare_three_way for ranges

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Why is there `std::lexicographical_compare_three_way`, but no `std::ranges::lexicographical_compare_three_way`?

There is argument Comp in `std::ranges::lexicographical_compare`, but it is rather useless, because function returns `bool`, when one of the comparison category types is expected.

Here are some links to cppref 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare_three_way 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/lexicographical_compare

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is there `std::lexicographical_compare_three_way`, but no `std::ranges::lexicographical_compare_three_way`?

The algorithms in `std::ranges` are constrained by `concept`s while the algorithms in `std` are not. So, for instance, `std::ranges::lexicographical_compare` (which uses a two-way comparison, defaulting to `<`) is specified as:

```cpp
template<input_­range R1, input_­range R2, class Proj1 = identity,
         class Proj2 = identity,
         indirect_­strict_­weak_­order<projected<iterator_t<R1>, Proj1>,
                                    projected<iterator_t<R2>, Proj2>> Comp = ranges::less>
  constexpr bool
    lexicographical_compare(R1&& r1, R2&& r2, Comp comp = {},
                            Proj1 proj1 = {}, Proj2 proj2 = {});
```

Notably, we have the concept [`indirect_strict_weak_order`](http://eel.is/c++draft/indirectcallable.indirectinvocable#concept:indirect_strict_weak_order) to explain the syntactic and semantic requirements for the comparison operation you need in order for this algorithm to be meaningful.

However, nobody has (yet) done the work to formulate the corresponding `concept`s for three-way comparison. Note that [`strict_weak_order`](http://eel.is/c++draft/concept.strictweakorder#concept:strict_weak_order) has very strong semantic requirements, and we would need the equivalent for a hypothetical `strict_weak_order_three_way` (or some other name that sucks less).

The interesting thing here is that we need to *not* reject `partial_ordering`, but rather only require that no two elements in the domain compare as `partial_ordering::unordered`.

Once we have such `concept`s, then specifying and implementing `std::ranges::lexicographical_compare_three_way` is pretty straightforward.